# Angular 17.2.0 does not support ConnectionServiceModule?

Tags: angular, typescript, compatibility, ivy, npm-package

[image]

I'm encountering an error in my Angular application related to the compatibility of the `ng-connection-service` library with `Angular Ivy`. When trying to import the `ConnectionServiceModule` from `ng-connection-service` into my Angular module, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: src/app/app.module.ts:39:5 - error NG6002: 'ConnectionServiceModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

39     ConnectionServiceModule
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/ng-connection-service/lib/ng-connection-service.module.d.ts:1:22
    1 export declare class ConnectionServiceModule {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                           
This likely means that the library (ng-connection-service) which declares ConnectionServiceModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

✖ Failed to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Package does not work with IVY start looking for alternate packages, if possible raise a github issue on their github page [`ng-connection-service`](https://github.com/ultrasonicsoft/ng-connection-service)

I already see an issue [related to IVY](https://github.com/ultrasonicsoft/ng-connection-service/issues/150)

But you need to move on from this package, until it gets fixed!